# Return from FOR ... IN in extension recursive method (F#)?

Tags: .net, f#, xamarin.ios

i newbe in F#. Can't deal with the syntax. I need to translate a recursive extension method from C # to F #. But whatever I do, the compiler doesn't like my code.

Here my method:

```
 public static class ViewExtensions
    {

        public static UIView FindFirstResponder(this UIView view)
        {
            if (view.IsFirstResponder)
            {
                return view;
            }
            foreach (UIView subView in view.Subviews)
            {
                var firstResponder = subView.FindFirstResponder();
                if (firstResponder != null)
                    return firstResponder;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I tried something like this:

```
  type UIKit.UIView with
     member this.FindFirstResponder() =
        let mutable firstResponder = null
        if (this.IsFirstResponder) then this
        else
          for subView in this.Subviews do
             firstResponder <- subView.FindFirstResponder()
```

But this is clearly not correct, and the compiler will not skip this. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the method's return type supposed to be? Is your code returning that type? Also, "clearly not correct" is not a good description of a problem. In the future please provide details.

Comment: The method should return a UIView type as above in C # code. Sorry for the possibly incorrect description of the problem, the first time in my life I ask a question on StackOverflow. No experience yet.

Comment: So what about my second question: is your code returning that type?

Comment: Now the compiler doesn't pass my code. The question is how to write the method that is written in C # (it works fine) using F #. I'm trying to translate it to F #, but the problem is that in F # I can't return from a FOR IN loop and I don't understand how to call the same method recursively in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F# doesn't have early return (which is what the `return` keyword in C# is doing). Every expression in F# has to be evaluated fully, top to bottom, and cannot be interrupted in the middle. This may feel strange coming from a C-like language, but it's actually a feature, trust me. It leads to more understandable, easier maintainable code.

The natural way to model iteration in F# is recursion. It can be easily interrupted at any step by simply not making the recursive call. But you don't have to use naked recursion in every situation, because for many common use cases there are already library functions (which are themselves built on recursion or other such functions).

In this particular case, the function of interest is [`Seq.tryPick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.trypick%5B%27t,%27u%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It takes the sequence and another function, which returns an `option` - either `Some` or `None`. Then `Seq.tryPick` will return the first `Some` it encounters, or `None` if there were no `Some`s in the sequence. To convert from a nullable .NET value to an `option`, use `Option.ofObj`, to convert back - use `Option.toObj`.

```
  type UIKit.UIView with
     member this.FindFirstResponder() =
        if this.IsFirstResponder then this
        else
          this.Subviews
          |> Seq.tryPick (fun v -> v.FindFirstResponder() |> Option.ofObj)
          |> Option.toObj
```

---

If you have to interact with C#, this is more or less the best you can do. Interop is always a bit ugly. But if you don't need C# anymore, I would recommend converting `IsFirstResponder`, `Subviews`, and `FindFirstResponder` from methods and properties to standalone functions and make `FindFirstResponder` return an `option` (which is the standard way of dealing with optional values in F#).

Then the function becomes a bit prettier:

```
let findFirstResponder view =
  if isFirstResponder view then Some view
  else view |> subViews |> Seq.tryPick findFirstResponder
```